# Seguridad paypal con php

Tags: php, paypal

Buenas, antes que nada decir que ya pase mucho tiempo investigando y no encuentro algo que me satisfaga. 
Resulta que no se puede hacer seguro de otra forma mas usar que el <strike>odioso</strike> form que nos proporciona paypal y validar con su ipn pero luego encuentro esto:
[Mirar ejemplo](http://cloudsrcsoft.com/Paypal/), osea no usa el form.

- no funciona header location
- no me sirve el CURL
- no sirve pasarlo por get
- no sirve el file_get_contents

Me gustaría que realmente alguien me eche una mano en esto si no es mucho pedir. Por cierto cuando digo que no sirve no me refiero a que la función no sirva, ojito con eso :)

Comment: upvote por el sentido del humor. En segundo lugar, qué hay que mirar en el link que pusiste? Tu pregunta es qué librería de PHP sirve para enviar peticiones POST?

Comment: Cuarto: ¿Te fijaste que si intentas pagar con el carrito vacío te muestra todas las características del request y el response? http://cloudsrcsoft.com/Paypal/paypal/comprar.php?total=0

Comment: El método que usa la aplicación del link que has dado es mediante el SDK de PayPal. Básicamente se crea un objeto con el `payment_method`, `transactions` y `redirect_urls` donde especificas las URL de éxito y error. Cuando creas un pago (`payment`) con el objeto recientemente creado, se te devuelve un objeto `payment` que tiene una propiedad llamada `links`.

Comment: Dentro de este array `links` hay varios objetos que tienen, entre otras, una propiedad llamada `method`. Debes extraer la URL (`link.href`) del link cuyo método sea igual a `REDIRECT`, así mismo debes guardar en sesión el `id` del `payment` ya que luego de redireccionar paypal a la URL de éxito que has especificado, se debe ejecutar la función `execute` del SDK de paypal para completar el pago.

Comment: Gracias por responder, @amenadiel busco la manera mas segura ( no formularios ni javascript y el ipn en un form también es editable ) para poder hacer el pago con paypal. Si me fije del link pero no tengo idea de que es por eso busco ayuda con esto. En serio muchas gracias.

Comment: @Guz, gracias por responder, estoy muy interesado en este método, cuando lo investigue pensé que era para poner solo mi cuenta paypal pero estaba muy equivocado. Veo que tienes experiencia en esto, pero estoy aprendiendo y me cuesta seguirte, podrías echarme una mano ( con alguna liga, ya que entiendo mucho mejor si lo veo y mas si esta en español hehe )? por otra parte voy a investigar a fondo este método. Gracias! ** la documentación de paypal es muy confusa para mi.

Comment: Yo trabajo con Node.js, pero el SDK es universal. Se hacen los mismos procedimientos para cada lenguaje. En [este artículo](http://ovedfs.com/07-implementar-pagos-con-paypal-taller-de-desarrollo-de-una-tienda-en-linea/) puedes ver cómo integrar PayPal SDk en tu proyecto (incluído vídeo).

Comment: @Guz Muchas gracias lo voy a ver :)

Comment: la pregunta es un poco vieja pero aqui te traigo un aporte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848227/validate-that-ipn-call-is-from-paypal

Answer (score 1):

Trata eston,

1.- Generar el formulario en tu sitio web

```js
 function activar(){
  
  var nombre = $("#nombre").val();
  var apellido = $("#apellido").val();
  var correo = $("#correo").val();
  var total = $("#total").val();
  var numerocliente = '001';
  var moneda = 'USD';
  var descuento = '0';
  
  window.location="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=cliente@paypal.com&currency_code="+moneda+"&item_name=nombredelaweb&charset=utf-8&amount="+total+"&discount_amount="+descuento+"&quantity=1&first_name="+nombre+"&last_name="+apellido+"&email="+correo+"&custom="+numerocliente+"";
  
  
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">
    <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido">
    <input type="text" name="correo" id="correo">
    <input type="number" name="total" id="total">
    <button type="button" onclick="activar()">ACTIVAR BOTON</button> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

esto en modo online te manda al formulario de paypal ya con los datos prellenados y puedes usar para que sea un poco dinámico, las posibilidades son infinitas

Y con respecto al ipn puedes configurar que la respuesta de los datos sea por medio de url, está en la configuración de paypal donde te redirecciona.